# JMeter GET request is returning 200 OK instead of 302 (redirect)

Tags: jmeter

JMeter POST request is returning 200 OK instead of 302 (redirect).Both Jmeter and Broswers, shows same set of request headers but still Browser response code is 302 ( which is expected) whereas Jmeter has 200

Answer (score 0):

With HTTP code 200 is the second request after loading the first request JMeter execute the redirect request then return HTTP code 302. And you will receive the code for all request is 200.

If you want to see the request with HTTP code is 302, unstick **Predirect Automatically** in HTTP request in JMeter 
[image]

If you did not set you will see 2 HTTP request like that.
[image]